# "NullReferenceException" error

Tags: nullreferenceexception, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a scoring system to my game. However I get this error whenever I play and the asteroids wont destroy anymore when they collide with either the player or a bullet.

My error message is this:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
DestroyByContact.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D other) (at Assets/Scripts/DestroyByContact.cs:47)

I should note that all game objects have the correct tags on them as well.

And some Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyByContact : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject explosion;
    public GameObject playerExplosion;
    public int scoreValue;
    private GameController gameController;

    void start () {
        GameObject gameControllerObject = GameObject.FindWithTag ("GameController");
        if (gameControllerObject != null) {
            gameController = gameControllerObject.GetComponent <GameController> ();
        }

        if (gameController == null)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Cannot find 'GameController' script");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        if (other.tag == "Boundary") {
            return;
        }

        Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);

         if (other.tag == "Player") {
            Instantiate(playerExplosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
        }

        gameController.AddScore (scoreValue);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] asteroids;
    public Vector3 spawnValues;
    public int asteroidCount;
    public float spawnWait;
    public float startWait;
    public float waveWait;

    public GUIText scoreText;
    private int score;

    void Start () {
        score = 0;
        UpdateScore ();
        StartCoroutine (spawnWaves ());
    }

    IEnumerator spawnWaves () {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (startWait);

        while (asteroidCount > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < asteroidCount; i++) {
                GameObject asteroid = asteroids[Random.Range(0, asteroids.Length)];
                Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3 (spawnValues.x, Random.Range (-spawnValues.y, spawnValues.y), spawnValues.z);
                Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
                Instantiate (asteroid, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (spawnWait);
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (waveWait);

            if (asteroidCount <= 95) {
                asteroidCount += 5;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddScore (int newScoreValue) {
        score += newScoreValue;
        UpdateScore ();
    }

    void UpdateScore () {
        scoreText.text = "Score:" + score;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is line 47 of `DestroyByContact.cs`? And how do you think the variable there is being set? A `NullReferenceException` is generally pretty trivial to debug: what have you done to try to understand the issue?

Comment: Line 47 is: gameController.AddScore (scoreValue);. And to be honest I'm new to this and I'm using some tutorials to try and learn. I'm not to sure how to debug this. One thing I do know is if I put line 47 below the destroy functions the it still works, but doesn't add the score (which I imagine is because the game object is no longer there to run the code).

Comment: Mark, instead of using FindWithTag assign GameController from hierarchy. And try again if you don't know how to do that share screenshot of your unity3d with us.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that better idea would be to set `gameController` after `Instantiate` inside Controller. If I understand it right, your `GameController` spawns asteroids that have `DestroyOnContact` attached from prefab/predefined collection?
If so, consider doing that way:

**GameController**

```
var go = Instantiate (asteroid, spawnPosition, spawnRotation) as GameObject;
if (destroyable != null)
{
   var destroyable = go.GetComponent<DestroyByContact>();
   if (destroyable == null)
   {
      //Something else got instantiated, destroy it as we don't need it here
      Destroy(destroyable);
   }
   else
   {
      destroyable.gameController = this;
   }
}
```

**DestroyOnContact**

```
//just change accessor from private to public
public GameController gameController;

//Get rid of stuff that would set gameController in Start()

//Also check if gameController != null before you call .AddScore()
```

Comment: I'm trying to reference the game controller script attached to my game controller gameobject so I can tell it to increase the player score when the asteroid is destroyed.

Comment: Nothings stops you from doing the other way round as I've shown you. Actually with proper dependency injection you should inject GameController from outside (constructor is not a valid way for MonoBehaviour unfortunately) as in my example instead of finding it from inside from DestroyOnContact.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this works. I've tried putting it into my code to no avail.